# My USB's corrupted post creating Windows boot USB on Ubuntu. Can't format.?

Tags: windows, operating-system, usb, partitioning, disk

I attempted to create a Windows 10 bootable USB on Ubuntu by mounting the downloaded ISO and transferring the files to the USB. However, the install.wim file exceeded 4GB, necessitating splitting for FAT32 systems. Despite copying the files individually and adding the source files last, both USBs are now corrupt. Formatting fails, files refuse deletion, and upon reboot, I encounter 'file descriptor error -71'. Attempting operations like unmounting with Disks or GParted causes crashes, requiring USB reconnection. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if there is unallocated freespace (see https://imgur.com/a/j6bXdNC) at the beginning of the USB. Create a partition on the unallocated freespace, and you will be able to format the rest of the corrupted USB.